# How to setup OpenID Connect to work with alias of the same identity provider?

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect

sorry if this question is very basic or maybe even wrong altogether.  I am completely new to OpenID Connect and inherited the project with no documentation from my predecessor.

We currently have an identity provider for all of our webapps.  let say

https://identity.company.com

however, one of our clients wants a login page of their own, so we just made their login page another binding of our identity web site.

https://customer.company.com

it is the same website as identity.company.com.

I was able to login to the identity server page where customer can select the scope/web app they want.

Once scope is selected the identity sever will redirect the customer to the correct web site/web app.

But the web app will fail authentication and redirect the customer to the normal login page (identity.company.com).

Is this because the new URL  customer.company.com is not an accepted issuer/referer?

I looked through the code everywhere, and the identity DB as well, but I couldn't find a place where I can add customer.company.com as a trusted identity provider.

Can anyone give me some hints on where to look or knows how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

**REQUIREMENTS**

I could be misunderstanding, but this is usually what is needed:

- Partner users login with familiar corporate credentials
- Partner administrators can control access, eg for people who leave / join the company
- No changes to the actual app itself

I am assuming that you host a single instance of your apps, via a single internet Url.

**PREREQUISITES**

Business partners must provide a standards compliant identity provider, that your system can integrate with. Do not accept other options that add lots of complexity to your apps.

**YOUR APPS**

Your UIs and APIs only redirect to your Authorization Server at this Url and receive tokens from it.

- https::/identity.company.com

During logins the AS can connect to many different identity providers for different business partners.

**PARTNER INTEGRATION**

Usually this requires just a few config changes:

- An OAuth Client to be configured in the Partner Identity Provider
- An Identity Provider entry to be added to your Authorization Server
- Partner users to add a query parameter to their app the first time they use it, such as https://web app.mycompany.com?idp=partner.com

**FURTHER DETAILS**

For some visual details, see my [Federated Logins Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/23/federation-logins/). There is an interactive code sample you can run also, to understand how it looks.